# How to handle boolean observables with the async pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following code:

```
public obs$: Observable<boolean>
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(obs$ | async) === true || (obs$ | async) === false">
  {{ (obs$ | async) ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
</div>
```

It works as intended, but the `if` looks a little verbose.

The problem is that I cannot simply do `<div *ngIf="(obs$ | async)">`. If I try that, it will work in the case when the observable did not emit a value yet or if the value is true, but it will not work if the value is false, because the if will evaluate to false and the div is not displayed.

I assume the same issue applies if a falsy value is returned, such as an empty string or 0.

Is there a better, easier way of doing that?

Comment: You can do `(obs$ | async) !== null`

Comment: Can you please shed some light on when the `Observable` will not emit a value?

Comment: @SachinGupta Oh wow, it is actually that simple. I tried to compare it to undefined which didn't work and I just gave up. Thanks a lot! If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I'm making an API call to get the value, so it sometimes takes a few seconds to emit a value.

Comment: You can also `pipe` the response and return a `false` in the `catchError` operator. That way you'd always be certain that a boolean value is emitted. And you won't have to use an `*ngIf` on the `div`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do `(obs$ | async) !== null`

Comment: You can't get value of boolean content in Observable with this solution, right?

Comment: Its a conditional check to be put in HTML, you wont get the value.

Answer (score 57):

Here's a way where you can share the subscription and not have to make any custom pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{value: obs$ | async} as context">
    {{context.value}}
</ng-container>
```

The `*ngIf` will evaluate to `true` no matter what (I believe) and then you can do your own tests on the `value` in the `context` object.

...would be better if they would just implement `*ngLet` I think!

The thing I like about this solution is that the resulting value is reusable with only the single use of an `async` pipe and its still pretty concise (even if it isn't perfect).

Comment: To add some clarity the `context` object is always defined so the `ng-container` will always show. 

To check if the `Observable` has completed use `context.value !== null` ... thanks, good answer

Comment: apart from the typo 'asyc' should be 'async' this solved my issue - thanks

Comment: Thanks for noticing that - should be fixed.

Comment: Is this still the way to go? Its working well, but feels hacky...

Comment: @enno.void you could try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-let

Comment: @WillyC thanks, i know the ng-let package, but im confused why something like this isnt backed into angular itself.

Comment: @enno.void you’re not kidding. Seems like a trivial thing to add and clearly in need.

Comment: Almost 2024 and Angular does not provide an easy way to do this natively

Answer (score 1):

You can use "!!" to evalulate to boolean.
for example *ngIf = "!!(item$ | async)"

Comment: simple and it works

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way should be creating a custom BoolPipe ， and chain it after the async pipe。

```
@Pipe({name: 'myBool'})
export class MyBoolPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean, exponent: string): string {
    return !value ? 'yes' : 'no';
  }
}
```

and init the obj$ in the constructor of your component or service (don't need null check in your HTML template),  then chain it with async pipe like this:

```
<div>{{ obs$ | async | myBool }}</div>
```

Comment: nothing elegant about that, you are just bloating up the code